# Which Bone is Leela Missing?

Tags: futurama, science

In Season 8, Episode 9 of Futurama, called "Fry Am the Egg Man", Leela says that she has 205 bones in her body. A normal human has 206 (at adulthood), so what bone is Leela missing?

Comment: I sort of remember a gag about her not having a sense of humor and hence missing a funny bone. but I could be misremembering. I can't find corroboration at the moment, maybe it will jog someone elses memory.

Comment: The inner orbital wall of each eye socket?

Comment: There's the problem that Futurama's humans only have four fingers, so they should have fewer bones than current humans, meaning Leela actually has **more** bones than regular humans in Futurama's reality, right?

Comment: ^^ Oh no, you're totally right! Good catch!

Comment: Man there are so many joke answers to this question I can't believe this isn't protected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can see from the image below (from [season 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebirth_(Futurama))) that Leela's skeleton is **completely normal from the neck down**. That would strongly imply that the bone that she's missing is within her skull or upper neck.

Presumably she's missing her [nasal bone](http://jcsx2.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/6/4/13642251/4443951_orig.jpg), since that would conflict with her big centrally-located eye.

[image]

Comment: But she does have a nose.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - Attached by a skin-flap, I think we can assume, or otherwise integrated into the maxilla plate. Note that it's much lower down her face than a normal nose

Answer (score 2):

As [Valorum shows](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120143/2287), her skeleton from the neck down appears normal. Indeed, the most significant difference between her (["the least-mutated mutant ever born"](https://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Leela%27s_Homeworld)) and a normal person is her one huge eye, suggesting that the one missing bone is part of her [facial skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_skeleton).

[image]

Since the facial bones are in pairs, the *one* she is missing is likely an unpaired one, specifically the [vomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomer), which makes sense given the size of her eye and the space it would occupy in her skull.